# No hibernate option in Windows 8.1 Pro tablet even after "powercfg -h on"

Tags: windows-8.1

The Hibernate option is missing on my Windows 8.1 Pro Update 1 tablet. It's neither in the Settings Charm (Power menu) nor in the Desktop Win+X menu.

Hibernation itself is enabled with `powercfg.exe /h on` and it actually works if invoked manually via `shutdown.exe /h`.

There is *no* Hibernate option available in Control Panel:

[image]

How do I get this option listed?

Comment: Is `powercfg.exe /h on` a replacement to http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/add-hibernation-option-windows-8-1-power-user-menu/

Comment: No, it is not a replacement. `Powercfg` has to be done first, then those UI manipulations. It my case, there's still no Hibernate option in that list in the Control Panel.

Comment: Try `shutdown /h`

Comment: sorry, I just misread that part

Comment: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-missing-hibernate-option-in-windows-8-power-menu/

Comment: please use http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-missing-hibernate-option-in-windows-8-power-menu/ its easier and better option than editing registry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it. The following .REG file enables the Hibernate option for Charm and Win+X menus:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FlyoutMenuSettings]
"ShowHibernateOption"=dword:00000001
"ShowLockOption"=dword:00000001
```

It's still not listed in Control Panel, but I don't care anymore.

**Updated**, on another machine I also had to use this .REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power]
"HibernateEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

And to run this:

```
powercfg.exe /h on 
powercfg /h /type full
```